# EDKII build errors on Windows -- Googled to no avail

Tags: build

I'm trying to create a EDKII build, I've installed VS2017, Nasm, Iasl, Python etc. I ran "edksetup.bat Rebuild" to get the \Conf\target.txt, which works perfectly fine. I've changed the Arch to X64, the VS build to VS2017 and when I want to build for MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc I get the following three errors:

1. Building ... c:\edk2\MdeModulePkg\Library\FmpAuthenticationLibNull\FmpAuthenticationLibNull.inf [X64]
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
   Stop.
2. build.py...
   : error 7000: Failed to execute command
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe /nologo tbuild [c:\edk2\Build\MdeModule\DEBUG_VS2017\X64\MdeModulePkg\Library\BrotliCustomDecompressLib\BrotliCustomDecompressLib]

3.build.py...
: error F002: Failed to build module
c:\edk2\MdeModulePkg\Library\BrotliCustomDecompressLib\BrotliCustomDecompressLib.inf [X64, VS2017, DEBUG]

[Here is a screenshot of current DEV VS CMD Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKGAJ.png)

It should be noted, that when I changed the ACTIVE_PLATFORM FROM MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc to ShellPkg/ShellPkg.dsc it actually builds and runs with a success message saying "Done"
I want to build MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc because I want the HelloWorld.efi files.
Would a workaround for this be to simply find the HelloWorld.efi online, copy and paste? I'd much rather fix these errors and get a successful build so I can get the modules.
What are the fixes for these errors?

Thank you very much for reading.

All help is greatly appreciated!

I used git submodule update --recursive and --init [two separate commands] to get Brotli etc.

EDIT:

```
C:\edk2>build -p MdeModule\MdeModulePkg.dsc -t VS2017 -a X64
Build environment: Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
Build start time: 18:51:11, Dec.19 2023

WORKSPACE        = c:\edk2
EDK_TOOLS_PATH   = c:\edk2\basetools
EDK_TOOLS_BIN    = c:\edk2\basetools\bin\win32
CONF_PATH        = c:\edk2\conf
PYTHON_COMMAND   = py -3

build.py...
 : error C0DE: Unknown fatal error when processing [c:\edk2\MdeModule\MdeModulePkg.dsc]
```

I am going to repeat all of my steps with VS2019. The error is unknown.

Comment: The "git submodule updae --init --recursive" didn't work, I had to use "git pull" and then upload the submodules. Got it to work.